# Use jessie (Debian) for Kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, google-compute-engine, gcsfuse

I want to set up gcsFUSE on my cluster. It's easier to do this in Debian jessie according to the [gcsFUSE page](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcsfuse).

The `config-default.sh` that `kube-up.sh` uses contains the following:

```
NODE_OS_DISTRIBUTION=${KUBE_NODE_OS_DISTRIBUTION:-${KUBE_OS_DISTRIBUTION:-debian}}
```

which sets up `wheezy`. What do I change this to to get `jessie`? I've tried replacing `debian` with the values `debian-8` and `jessie`, without any luck:

```
$ cluster/kube-up.sh
Cannot operate on cluster using node os distro: jessie
```

Answer (score 1):

from reading the [cluster/gce/util.sh](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/cluster/gce/util.sh) you can use `KUBE_GCE_MASTER_IMAGE` / `KUBE_GCE_MASTER_PROJECT` and `KUBE_GCE_NODE_IMAGE` / `KUBE_GCE_NODE_PROJECT` for that purpose.

E.g. with:

```
  KUBE_GCE_MASTER_IMAGE=debian-8-jessie-v20170124   
  KUBE_GCE_MASTER_PROJECT=debian-8
  KUBE_GCE_NODE_IMAGE=debian-8-jessie-v20170124 
  KUBE_GCE_NODE_PROJECT=debian-8
```

You can find the relevant images on the with:

```
gcloud compute images list --filter=debian
```

These environment variables are used to then create the instances with

```
 gcloud compute instance-templates create ...
```

The [related documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instance-templates/create#--image) has some further details.

Comment: When I list relevant images using the command you suggested, I get "debian-8-jessie-v20170124". However, if I put this value in the config-default.sh file as mentioned, I get "Cannot operate on cluster using node os distro: debian-8-jessie-v20170124".

Comment: The four settings you mention - where should I set these? Do I just leave the NODE_OS_DISTRIBUTION setting as it was (set to Debian)?

Comment: Just set these as environment variables for your kube-up.sh ... NODE_OS_DISTRIBUTION  should be "debian"